# Recursive method that prints a linked list in reverse order

Tags: java

I'm having trouble writing a method that should accept a reference to a generic single-linked list and creating a test program to testing my method on a list of strings (print the list both in-order and reverse-order). I have already created a single-linked list called SinglyLinkedList.

Comment: If this is a `homework` question, please tag it appropriately. This hints people to provide more explanation which should be helpful to you!

Comment: And if it isn't a homework question, don't do it. Recursion isn't an appropriate technique for dealing with linear data structures in general.

Comment: @EJP Wait what? Recursion isn't the right tool to work with lists? I assume someone should tell the Lisp people to rename their language.

Comment: @Voo I agree with you that EJP's statement is incorrect as stated, but when you consider the question is tagged Java, it would seem in that context it is accurate. You would not want to use recursion for list operations (especially considering you're incredibly unlikely to have a Single Linked List in Java production code).

Comment: @Voo Irrelevant. The question and my comment both concern Java.

Comment: @glowcoder Then it's rather strange formulated - "in general" but only for java? Also even then it's not generally true, e.g. a mergesort for a linked list is probably much simpler with recursion than iterative. I just thought it was a rather general formulation for something that's by far not that clear-cut.

Comment: @Voo I suspect EJP was speaking less from a theoretical point of view and instead from a practical point of view. In Java production environments, you typically never see linked lists. If you need a one dimensional structure, you almost always use ArrayList, which of course lends itself less to recursion. (If you needed to insert somewhere in the middle, you'd use a SortedSet or SortedMap instead.) In fact, if I were sorting a linked list in Java, I'd dump it to an array first so I could get the local access.

Comment: @Voo ..cont.. Consider my answer to stackoverflow.com/q/7801003/ - There's a good profiling link there. It was enough to make a believer out of me that a Java LinkedList in production environments is just a bad idea. Now I respect your defense of recursion, and in a language like Lisp, specifically designed for recursion (including tail recursion, which Java doesn't support to the best of my knowledge) you simply need it.

Comment: @glowcoder I didn't regard it as a solely practical statement. Sadly the rep doesn't exist any longer - but certainly linkedLists do have their cache problems. Though it should get better after a GC run (they should be close together just as arrays in theory, but we're wasting lots of cache). The java STL does dump the list into an array before sorting and I'm intrigued to benchmark this against the in-place algorithm. Anyways linked lists are really only useful if I need some order and have to insert in the middle of the structure (umn.. priority queues? that's rare in itself).

Comment: @glowcoder cont. Anyways my gripe wasn't about not using linked lists or recursion with linked lists, but more about what I regarded as a rather general statement against recursion - the scheme personality inside me broke free and maybe I just misinterpreted it ;-) (though I still think it's at least a good idea to learn all the concepts even if you don't use them in Java) But don't worry I'll have to castigate myself with some nice VHDL code sometime next week anyhow  :(

Comment: @Voo good luck with teh VHDL. My 9-5 (more accurately, my 8-7...) gives me the joy of "Progress 4GL". :-\

Answer (score 13):

Well if you think about recursion, you know you're going to be doing something over and over again. In this case we want to print a node over and over, but we want a different node each time.

Our first node we print should be the last in the list. That indicates to me an excellent base case.

```
void printReverse(Node node) {
    if(node.next != null) { // we recurse every time unless we're on the last one
        printReverse(node.next);  // this says "do this to the next node first"
    }
    System.out.println(node.data); // we'll print out our node now
}
```

Consider if you had

1,2,3,4

You'd call print on the node with 1 in it. It would then say "I have a next node, print that". The 2 node also has a next node, so it defers to node 3. Node 3 still has a next node, so it defers to node 4 before printing. Node 4 is willing to print itself since it has no next node. Then it returns to where node 3 left off. Now node 3 can print and go back to where node 2 left off. It prints and goes to where node 1 left off. It prints and returns to the main function.

Comment: Personally, my favorite thing about this answer is the talking nodes. Nodes are better when they say things like "I have a next node" and such.

Answer (score 6):

For in-order, call the output method before calling the function recurisvely.

```
void print(Node n)
{
    if ( n != null )
    {
        System.out.println(n.value);
        print(n.next);
    }
}
```

For reverse, call the function first and the output.

```
void print(Node n)
{
    if ( n != null )
    {        
        print(n.next);
        System.out.println(n.value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree 100% with the answers above, for my implementation I could not get this to work without a helper class. My answer is only to expand on the answers above, in case others get compilation errors too.

```
public void printReverse()
{
 printReverse(head);
}

private void printReverse(GNode<T> node)
{
  if (node.next != null) 
   {
     printReverse(node.next);
   }
  System.out.println(node.data);
}
```